# css que solo afecte a safari

Tags: css, safari

Queria hacer unos cambios que solo afectara al navegador de safari y no consigo como, tengo esto pero de momento no funciona

```
@supports (-webkit-text-size-adjust:none) and (not (-ms-ime-align:auto)) 
and (not (-moz-appearance:none)) { 
/* Estos estilos solo los ejecutara Safari */
::i-block-chrome, .elementor-3519 {
  -webkit-margin-top:120px
    }

}
```

en este codigo he borrado '-webkit- y '::i-block-chrome' pero sigue sin funcionarme, alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

En principio lo he conseguido con esto :

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (stroke-color:transparent) {
body { margin-top:121px;
    }
  }
}
```

Espero que le pueda servir a otros